# namenode not starting with no exception

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am stuck could someone help on hadoop cluster?

I run a small cluster (1 master, 1 secondary and 3 slaves) on AWS. start-dfs result of everything starting EXCEPT the name node on Slave3 (1 and 2 start as expected...). 
While troubleshouting the logs I noticed no Exception/Error/Warn on the Slave3 nor Master.

Any idea?

Note. there was a strange message on the Master but do not know if related (and not sure why related to Slave 3 and not 2 or 1 ...). anyway, here are the logs
from master

**WARN** org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one image storage directory (dfs.namenode.name.dir) configured. Beware of data loss due to lack of redundant storage directories!

**WARN** org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one namespace edits storage directory (dfs.namenode.edits.dir) configured. Beware of data loss due to lack of redundant storage directories!

Your comments are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I fixed it here is how I did it. just typed the following and then data nodes where up and running (replace hadoop_install with your own)

$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes